# Why does password strength matter?

Tags: hash, passwords, brute-force

I'm seeing it this way, if a company can properly protect their hashes and they can prevent brute force attacks against their authentication system, then why do passwords need to really have any strength at all?

If someone can't get the hashes and they can't brute-force, then the passwords are relatively safe, no?

Of course the easy answer is "yeah but, the hashes aren't always kept safe". But look at it from the perspective of the business. If they require users to keep a strong password, they're basically admitting that they can't both protect the hashes and prevent brute force attacks. So it's a company who is putting the onus on their users for their own failings, no?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions, not general discussions. There are literally hundreds of articles available with a simple Google search about the benefits of using strong passwords. Voting to close as not constructive, as you're asking for a conversation here. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more details about the types of questions that should (and should not) be asked here. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Forget hashes or the security of the environment: **Passwords can be guessed.**

Comment: Usually a hacker tries to get your database (SQL-injection), then he can brute force offline in his own local environment. How easy such an sql-injection can be done, i tried to demonstrate in this [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/hash_sqlinjection.php), just click the next button to get a prepared input.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your password is `"a"`, a dismally weak password <sup>(a)</sup>.

Even without the hash, it would take me about ... well, hardly any time at all to crack that with a brute force approach.

The hashes may make it easier, but lack of the hashes doesn't necessarily make it impossible.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: This is why I always use the password `"b"` - it takes twice as long to crack :-)

Answer (score 1):

Password hashes and salts make the password secure when stored in the database, they do not protect against front-end cracking.

A brute force cracker will run agains a website trying everything from a-999 etc... A simple password of `abc` will be cracked in no time at all, no matter how secure the hash and salt is.